# detecting natural device orientation in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there a way to read the **natural** device orientation in Cordova?

For a normal smartphone that would be "portrait", while most tablets are meant to be held in "landscape" orientation (so that hardware buttons are at the optimal position).

Alternatively, can I tell if an Android device is a tablet, somehow?

PS: "natural" as described [here](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#dfn-natural):

> **Natural** is an orientation that refers to either `portrait-primary` or
> `landscape-primary` depending on the device's usual orientation. This
> orientation is usually provided by the underlying operating system.

Comment: [Canonical link for what "natural" means](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#dfn-natural): *"**Natural** is an orientation that refers to either `portrait-primary` or `landscape-primary` depending on the device's usual orientation. This orientation is usually provided by the underlying operating system."*